# How can I make my .Net5 project use a specific runtime?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5

There's currently a bug in Runtime 5.0.4 and I want to run against 5.0.3/2. How can I make my application use a specific runtime version?

Sadly I'm unable to get rid of 5.0.4 via normal uninstalls and without risking my VS installation so for the time being I would like to manually pick the .Net5 runtime version.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
        <PropertyGroup>
          <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
          <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
          <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
          <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        </PropertyGroup>
    ...
    </Project>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#self-contained-deployments-include-the-selected-runtime

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, this does work but sadly you have to go through the process of publishing a self-contained deployment. I suppose there's no other way to force an older runtime other multiple uninstalls/reinstalls?